# Detecting pasted shape (or object) within an image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to find a way to reliably determine the location of a puzzle piece in an image. The puzzle piece varies in both shape and how easy it is to find it. What algorithm(s) in the opencv module would help me with the task at hand? Or is what I'm trying to do beyond the scope of the module?

Example images below:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

### Update

The original title was "Detecting obscure shapes with Opencv Python". However I am interested in concepts of image-processing that would solve such a problem: How to find a pasted image inside the bigger image?

Assume the following:

- The jigsaw shapes are **always** of **same** (rectangle) boundary **size** (*ie:* a template-based searching method could work).
- The jigsaw shape is **not rotated** to any **angle** (*ie:* there will be straight(-*ish*) horizontal and vertical lines to find.
- The jigsaw shape is always "**pasted**" **into** some other "**original**" image (*ie:* a paste-detection method could work).

The solution can be OpenCV (as requested by the asker), but the core concepts should be applicable when using any appropriate software (*ie:* can loop through image pixels to process their values, in order to achieve the described solution).

I myself use JavaScript, but of course I will understand that `openCV.calcHist()` becomes a histogram function in JS code. I have no problem translating a good explanation into code. I will consider OpenCV code as pseudo-code towards a working idea.

Comment: you should reach into the game process and extract the position of the pieces from its memory directly. this task, approached visually, WILL require AI.

Comment: If you want to solve it with a func: "cv2.find_puzzle" - unlikely. For some cases like the first cat, edge detection/contours may find the piece at once, but for ones like with the dog, it's likely a multi-step CV problem. Also, they do vary in shape, but are they always similar to the above (could it be more "strange", sharp or simple etc.). Do they vary in size, could they be rotated in any angle etc. 
The general shape and size of the puzzle pieces may be a hint, searching for areas with similar borders etc., if finding something, making a hypothesis and checking whether the rest fit etc.

Comment: What are the images, are there many sample ones; are they known in advance etc. (I guess the pieces are unknown, probably the images too).

Comment: https://www.abtosoftware.com/blog/computer-vision-powers-automatic-jigsaw-puzzle-solver

Comment: @MonerOwner I need a universal `image-processing` answer, not just a Python/OpenCV method. The answer can then later be applied using any suitable tools (_ie_ OpenCV for those who choose it). I hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: the "solution" boils down to constructing some (fully) convolutional neural network and training it to do segmentation. expect it to learn the usual shapes of the puzzle pieces. it'll definitely latch onto the "paleness" of the background image.

Comment: @MonerOwner Please share the images with original resolution! This will make it more probable that someone can help you.

Comment: I would postulate that the problem is really finding where the background is no longer the background more than finding a puzzle shaped piece. Without the puzzle piece having a consistent border or shadow, the algorithm has to know that part of a cat face is missing or that the illusion of depth on the porch stairs is broken to "see" the puzzle piece.

Comment: @SargeATM Maybe you should expand that hypothesis into an Answer. I'm open to descriptive answers (_ie_ no code needed).

Comment: I've edited the post so that it might be more helpful to future readers. The main feedback that I would offer is two-fold: (1) if you have clarifications, they should go at the end of a post, so that future readers can read the question in the order it was written; (2) bounties are not a way of purchasing work, and thus it is best not to use them to set demands or requirements. They are either used to reward existing answers or to get more eyeballs on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Histogram of Largest Error

This is a rough concept of a possible algorithm.

The idea comes from an unfounded premise that seems plausible enough.
The premise is that adding the puzzle piece drastically changes the histogram of the image.

Let's assume that the puzzle piece is bounded by a 100px by 100px square.
We are going to use this square as a mask to mask out pixels that are used to calculate the histogram.

The algorithm is to find the placement of the square mask on the image such that the error between the histogram of the masked image and the original image is maximized.

There are many norms to experiment with to measure the error: You could start with the sum over the error components squared.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the original image to get the histogram of the original image?

Comment: The original image is the one with the puzzle piece without the mask applied.

Comment: Of course, got it!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best approach for a canonical answer was suggested in the comments by Christoph, which is training a CNN:

1. Implement a generator for shapes of puzzle pieces.
2. Get a large set of natural images from the net.
3. Generate tons of sample images with puzzle pieces.
4. Train your model to detect those puzzle pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in my own attempt. It fails on the first image, only works fine on the next two images. I am open to other pixel-processing based techniques where possible.

**I do not use OpenCV** so the process is explained with words (and pictures). It is up to the reader to **implement the solution** in their own chosen programming language/tool.

**Background**:
I wondered **if there was something inherent in pasted images** (something maybe revealed by pixel processing or even by frequency domain analysis, *eg:* could a Fourier signal analysis help here?).

After some research I came across **Error Level Analysis** (or ELA). This page has [a basic introduction](https://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php) for beginners.

**Process:** In 7 easy steps, this detects the location of a pasted puzzle piece.

**(1)** Take a provided cat picture and re-save 3 times as JPEG in this manner:

- Save copy #1 as JPEG of quality setting **2**.
- Reload (to force a decode of) copy #1 then re-save copy #2 as JPEG of quality setting **5**.
- Reload (to force a decode of) copy #2 then re-save copy #3 as JPEG of quality setting **2**.

**(2)** Do a **difference** blend-mode with original cat picture as base layer versus the re-saved copy #3 image. Thimage will be black so we increase **Levels**.

[image]

**(3)** Increase **Levels** to make the **ELA** detected area(s) more visible. 
 *note:* I recommend working in BT.709 or BT.601 grayscale at this point. Not necessary, but it gives "cleaner" results when blurring later on.

**(4)** Alternate between applying a **box blur** to the image and also increasing levels, to a point where the islands disappear and a large blob remains..

**(5)** The blob itself is also emphasized with an increase of levels.

**(6)** Finally a Gaussian blur is used to smoothen the selection area

[image]

**(7)** Mark the blob area (draw an outline stroke) and compare to input image...

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution. This uses JPEG to do a "weighted" frequency analysis where frequencies that affect perception are more evident in the compression error. You can see where the puzzle piece over the cat's face varies smoothly on the left side of the piece and therefore isn't picked up in the error analysis.